# Poisson process in a restaurant

Tags: poisson-process

While preparing for a midterm, I came across this question

> Suppose a restaurant is visited by 10 clients per hour on average, and clients follow a homogeneous Poisson Process. Independantly of other client, each client has a 20% chance to eat here and 80% to take away. In average, how many clients should be expected before one eats here ?

Proposed answer :

- 8
- 4
- 2

For me the correct answer is 4, but many of friends have answered "2" because they've decomposed the poisson into two poisson process one of parameter 0.2*10 and another one with parameter 0.8*10.

Who is right? The question is really tricky, isn't it?

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rate at which clients arrive does not matter.  All that matters is that each client has $0.2$ chance to eat here, so the expectation of the geometric distribution is $5$ clients before one eats here.  As the question is written, you are asked about how many not counting the one that eats here, so your $4$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ clients arrive before one eats at the restaurant, and take $T$ as the arrival time of the first client to eat at the restaurant. Then $T\sim \exp(2)$ and $X|T\sim \text{Poisson}(8T)$. We get for $x=0,1,2,...$ that $$\begin{eqnarray*}P(X=x)&=&\int_0^{\infty}P(X=x|T=t)f_{T}(t)\mathrm{d}t \\ &=& \int_0^{\infty}{e^{-8t}(8t)^x \over x!}\cdot2e^{-2t}\mathrm{d}t \\ &=& (0.8)^x\cdot 0.2\end{eqnarray*}$$ So, $$\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}x(0.8)^x(0.2)=4$$